# Method has incompatible type

Tags: scala

I have a trait that implements a Java interface

Java interface:

```
public interface Scheme extends Serializable {
    List<Object> deserialize(ByteBuffer var1);

    Fields getOutputFields();
}
```

Scala trait:

```
trait JSONScheme extends Scheme {

  type Event <: AnyRef

  override def deserialize(bytes: ByteBuffer): util.List[Event] = {
    val v: Seq[Event] = parseData(bytes)
    v.asJava
  }  
}
```

The question is why this does not work, as the `Event` type is defined to be bounded by `AnyRef`? This fails with:

```
Error:(35, 16) overriding method deserialize in trait Scheme of type (x$1: java.nio.ByteBuffer)java.util.List[Object];
 method deserialize has incompatible type
  override def deserialize(bytes: ByteBuffer): util.List[Event] = {
```

If I rewrite the code to add `Event` manually to the Java collection, it works fine.

```
override def deserialize(bytes: ByteBuffer): util.List[AnyRef] = {
   val v: Seq[Event] = parseData(bytes)
   val vArray = new util.ArrayList[AnyRef]()
   v.map(vArray.add(_))
   vArray
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java lists are invariant in their element type, so `List[Event]` isn't a subclass of `List[Object]`, and that makes your method incompatible: it's return type must be a subclass of the return type of the overridden method.

Your second snippet works not because you "add `Event` manually", but because the method is declared to return `List[AnyRef]` rather than `List[Event]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When adding elements to the Java list, how come that it accepts `Event` type in the second version?

Comment: Well, `Event` is a subclass of `AnyRef`, and that's an "Is a..." relationship (all "dogs" are "animals", all `Event`s are `AnyRef`s), which means that you can pass it anywhere `AnyRef` is expected. You can add `Event` to `List[AnyRef]`, but you can't _get_ the `Event` back (without casting) - `list.get(0)` still returns `AnyRef`. If this was `List[Event]`, it would be `Event`, that you get from it.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.